# sparklyr- JAVA_HOME is set but does not point to a valid version

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm attempting to use `sparklyr` to analyze a large dataset in R. Upon my attempts to establish a Spark connection with `spark_connect`, I receive the following error:

```
Error in get_java(throws = TRUE) : Java is required to connect to Spark. JAVA_HOME is set but does not point to a valid version. Please fix JAVA_HOME or reinstall from: https://www.java.com/en/
```

I've reinstalled Java but continue to get the same error. Any advice?

Comment: What does `Sys.which("java")` (from the R console) return?

Comment: java 
"C:\\PROGRA~2\\COMMON~1\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe"

Answer (score 2):

When I run:

```
sparklyr:::get_java()
           java 
"/usr/bin/java"
```

It appears that you don't have java set up in such a manner that the response for that `sparklyr` function is satisfactory. Unlike @Kerie I get nothing from the echo command. Instead, I can get sensible results from this command in a Terminal session:

```
$ java -version
#-------------------
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Running MacOS 10.11.6 (not upgraded because my hardware is "obsolete" per Apple) and R 3.5.1.

There's an irony here in that it appears that the get_java function is supposed to set a value for the location if it cannot find an environment variable. Here's the code:

```
sparklyr:::get_java
 #----------
function (throws = FALSE) 
{
    java_home <- Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME", unset = NA)
    if (!is.na(java_home)) {
        java <- file.path(java_home, "bin", "java")
        if (identical(.Platform$OS.type, "windows")) {
            java <- paste0(java, ".exe")
        }
        if (!file.exists(java)) {
            if (throws) {
                stop("Java is required to connect to Spark. ", 
                  "JAVA_HOME is set but does not point to a valid version. ", 
                  "Please fix JAVA_HOME or reinstall from: ", 
                  java_install_url())
            }
            java <- ""
        }
    }
    else java <- Sys.which("java")
    java
}
<bytecode: 0x7fb5c7f2db30>
<environment: namespace:sparklyr>
```

Because I do not have an environment variable for JAVA_HOME, but do have `java` registered with `which`, the `get_java` function returns a valid path. So my system returns:

```
Sys.which("java")
           java 
"/usr/bin/java"
```

From comments by @user6910411, I am reminded that you should not update to the current Java Dev Kit (which is 1.9), but do rather use the link provided by @Kerie to the prior major version, 1.8. You should also run:

```
Sys.unsetenv("JAVA_HOME")
```

to get rid of the misleading symlink. Or perhaps you could track it down at `/Library/Java/Home` (if that's where it is) and delete it before installing the newer (but not newest) version.

Comment: My output upon running `$ java -version` looks identical to yours. Similarly, when I run `sparklyr:::get_java()`, the output reads `/usr/bin/java`. Any idea how my Java might be set up differently?

Comment: It's perfectly possible that `sparklyr` expects to find an environment variable (despite being able to find java components in the PATH variable. What happens when you set one in one of your profile files? See: `?Startup` for a full listing of your options. I would advise against using your bash .profile. The environments are sometimes different.

Answer (score 0):

Run `echo $JAVA_HOME` in terminal, and see what is the output.

In my Mac OS, the output is :
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: @Kyle How did you install java? Is that JDK or JRE? Try download JDK from the [official download site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). Choose `jdk-8u181-macosx-x64.dmg`, which is about 242.83 MB.

Comment: @Kyle. I also have a symlink at `/Library/Java/Home` and it's dated 2009 and points to an invalid location. I think it is a remnant of an earlier installation. I currently have the symlink at `/usr/bin/java` pointing to code in `jdk1.8.0_131.jdk`. I'm thinking you may need to update your installation of java.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the Java path you mentioned in the comment was placed before `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` or directly added to the Path or there is no `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` variable in your Windows machine.

Below Steps should fix your Java path issue.

Got To System Variables.

If you haven't added `JAVA_HOME` please add it in the System Variables sections. Like the below example.

[image: Java Home set]

Select Path Variable is System Variables click Edit.

There should be a Java path like `C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.ex`e
in Path. Delete it.
Click `New` and add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
Now Your correct Java path should be set.
Open a new Command prompt and type `java -version` should be settled. (Already opened command prompts will not reflect this in Windows)

Please note that sometimes This won't affect IDEs like IntelliJ because of their advanced cache systems. You have to clear those caches. Otherwise, it won't be shown as Java was changed even though already changed in OS.