Java is required to connect to Spark
I got this error.
sc <- spark_connect(master="local", version="3.5.1")

Error in spark_get_java(throws = TRUE) :
Java is required to connect to Spark. JAVA_HOME is set to 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe' but does not point to a valid version. Please fix JAVA_HOME or reinstall from: https://www.java.com/en/

I reinstalled Java two times but no progress

Related, possible duplicate post https://stackoverflow.com/q/52827672/680068
